# Spring Batch + Spring Boot + Couchbase

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, couchbase

I am trying to create a tasklet and write into couchbase.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration extends 
   DefaultBatchConfigurer {
@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilders;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders;

  @Bean
public Step updatedatabaseStep(){
return stepBuilders.get("updatedatabaseStep").tasklet(new UpdateLocalDbStep()).build();}
```

My Step

```
public class UpdateLocalDbStep implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {
@Autowired
private CouchBaseRepository 
   couchBaseRepository;
  @Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
couchBaseRepository.save(this.table);
return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

My Couchbase service

```
@Repository
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "ownerDetails")
public class CouchBaseRepository {}
```

Every time I am getting a null pointer exception when I am executing the step stating that CouchBaseRepository is null

```
2018-11-12 18:59:10.435  INFO 56531 --- [                   
main] c.p.r.s.impl.steps.UpdateLocalDbStep     
: Updating local db with lated table 
info_incr
2018-11-12 18:59:10.440 ERROR 56531 --- [           
main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         
: Encountered an error executing step 
updatedatabaseStep in job findOwnerJob

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at
```

com.restbatchApi.service.impl.steps.UpdateLocalDbStep.execute(UpdateLocalDbStep.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
    at 
  org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]

Comment: We have to do some batch processing and I have just started with understanding  spring-batch. We also have a couchbase db. As far as I understood, spring-batch doesn't out of the box support couchbase. What challenge did you face while working with spring batch + couchbase. Also how did you handle the jobrepository bean and especially the transaction manager (since their is no concept of transactions in couchbase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the tasklet with `new UpdateLocalDbStep()` so this instance is not managed by the Spring container and hence dependencies of this object will not be injected.

You need to declare the tasklet as a bean:

```
@Bean
public Tasklet tasklet() {
   return new UpdateLocalDbStep();
}
```

and refer to it in your step definition:

```
@Bean
public Step updatedatabaseStep(){
   return stepBuilders.get("updatedatabaseStep").tasklet(tasklet()).build();
}
```

As a side note, I would recommend constructor injection for your tasklet (creating a constructor with the `CouchBaseRepository` as a parameter).

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud Ben Hassine